# unable to use Jenkins environment variable in pipeline script

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, webhooks, microsoft-teams

I am using HTTP Request plugin in Jenkins and using declarative pipeline script where in I have a stage to call Microsoft teams incoming webhook url and post message when build starts. My Stage looks like below

```
stage('Build Notification'){
steps{
script{

def payload = '''{
    "@type": "MessageCard",
    "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
    "themeColor": "0076D7",
    "summary": "Larry Bryant created a new task",
    "sections": [{
        "activityTitle": "![TestImage](https://47a92947.ngrok.io/Content/Images/default.png)Larry Bryant created a new task",
        "activitySubtitle": "On Project Tango",
        "activityImage": "https://teamsnodesample.azurewebsites.net/static/img/image5.png",
        "facts": [{
            "name": "Assigned to",
            "value": "Unassigned"
        }, {
            "name": "Build Number",
            "value": "${BUILD_NUMBER}"
        }, {
            "name": "Status",
            "value": "Not started"
        }],
        "markdown": true
    }]
   
}'''
httpRequest httpMode: 'POST', requestBody: payload, responseHandle: 'NONE' , url: 'blah/blah/blah', wrapAsMultipart: false
}
}
}
```

My issue is when this message is showing up in   teams ,Build Status is literally displaying as ${BUILD_NUMBER } instead of giving the real build number .
I tried to echo ${BUILD_NUMBER} and its giving build number which proves its working but I am unable to find out why ${BUILD_NUMBER} given inside payload of http request is not replaced with real build number while sending the request

I am new to pipeline and stuck on this for last 2 days . Please help

Comment: According to the [groovy language specification](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_triple_single_quoted_string) section 4.4.1: `Any Groovy expression can be interpolated in all string literals, apart from single and triple-single-quoted strings.`

Comment: Use `def payload = """ ... """`.

Comment: @MaratC That did the trick . Thanks a lot . I was behind this for last 2 days .Thanks a ton !!!